# page navigation MVC 5

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page with questions, with a foreach loop in generate  to store each question. So I don't know how many questions will be generated in advance. I want to keep the maximum amount of questions to about 20, for every 20 you need to be able to go to the next page. How can I limit the amount of questions to 20 on each page and use a toolbar button group, with the buttons 1,2,3,... and a next button

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference Bootstrap to do this. Example:

This is presuming you have a controller called "QuestionController", 2 folders called "Question" and "QuestionsPartial" the Views folder, with a view called "QuestionView" in the "Question" folder, and a partial view called "_questionResults" in the "QuestionsPartial" folder.

This would be your view:

```
@using PageResource = ProjectName.Resources.Question
@model ProjectName.Models.Question

@{
    ViewBag.Title = PageResource.PageTitle; 
}

<div> 

@if(Model.Questions.Any())
{
    using (Ajax.BeginForm("QuestionView", "Question", new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "questionList",
            HttpMethod = "get",
            LoadingElementId = "loading",
            OnSuccess = "addPaginationStyle",
            OnFailure = "failurePaging"
        }))                
    {
        <div id="questionList">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("QuestionsPartial/_questionResults", Model); }
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    <br/>
    <p class="lead text-danger">@string.Format(PageResource.NoQuestionsFound)</p>
}
</div>
```

And in your Partial view:

```
@using MvcPaging
@model ProjectName.Models.Question

@if (Model.TotalItemCount > 0)
{
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Question</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Title</td>
                <td>@item.Description</td>   @* The actual question *@
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

  if (Model.HasNextPage || Model.HasPreviousPage)
  {
  <!-- Paging Bar -->
    <div>
        @Html.Raw(Ajax.Pager(
            new Options
                {
                    PageSize = Model.PageSize,
                    TotalItemCount = Model.TotalItemCount,
                    CurrentPage = Model.PageNumber,
                    ItemTexts = new ItemTexts { Next = "Next", Previous = "Previous", Page = "P" },
                    ItemIcon = new ItemIcon { First = "glyphicon glyphicon-backward", Previous = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left", Next = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right", Last = "glyphicon glyphicon-forward" },
                    Size = Size.normal,
                    Alignment = Alignment.centered,
                    IsShowControls = true,
                    IsShowFirstLast = true,
                },
            new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = "questionList",
                    OnSuccess = "addPaginationStyle",
                    OnFailure = "failurePaging"
                }, new { controller = "Question", action = "QuestionView", questionId = Model.QuestionId  }))

        <div class="well">
            Showing <span class="badge">@Model.ItemStart</span> to <span class="badge">@Model.ItemEnd</span>
            of <span class="badge">@Model.TotalItemCount</span> entries.
        </div>
    </div>
    }
}
```

Add this to the "_Layout.cshtml" view in the "Shared" folder, which is inside the "View" folder:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Then add this to "BundleConfig.cs" inside the App_Start" folder:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  // other Bootstrap components you want, e.g.:
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"));
```

EDIT: added some of the Javascript functions which I forgot!

Add these to the "global.js" file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Ajax.Pager method doesn't place the bootstrap class on the correct element
    // Add pagination class to "ul" element and remove it from the "div" element
    ($('.pagination').length) {
        addPaginationStyle();
});

function failurePaging() {
    alert("Could not retrieve paged list.");
}

function addPaginationStyle() {
    $('.pagination ul:first').addClass('pagination');
    $('.pagination:first').removeClass();
}
```

Comment: I found the answer on a site of ASP.NET. I needed to install an extra package called Mvc pagedlist: Install-Package PagedList.Mvc
You need a constant defining the number of questions I wanted per page. And define at what page you where